# What is the maximum outbound connections I can create from AWS Lambda?

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am looking at the documentation on [Lamba Limits](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) which says:

> Number of file descriptors    1,024

I am wondering if this is per invoking lambda or total across all lambdas?

I am processing a very large number of items from a kinesis stream and I am calling a web endpoint and it I seem to be hitting a bottle neck of about 1024 concurrent connections to the API and I'm not sure where the bottleneck is. I'm investigating limits on my load balancer and instances but I'm also wondering if lambda itself simply cannot create more than 1024 concurrent outbound connections across all lambdas?

Comment: It's per invocation, not across all lambdas, however as the page states there is a limit of 1000 concurrent lambdas per region

Comment: Thanks. I have 32 concurrent lambdas I think. But each one is making up to 1000 outbound connections; so 32,000 connections to the server max. However I'm seeing only about 500 requests per second and the rest are getting 5xx errors from the gateway. So it seem like the gateway somehow has its own connection limiter.

Comment: It turns out it is across all lambdas not per invocation. There is a measurable bottleneck with outbound connections limited at 1024 across all invocations of a lambda function.

Comment: If I recall correctly I was wrong about the shared connection limits and was ultimately able to get it configured higher. It was some limitation on my server, I can't remember what it was some nginx config or docker itself which was hosting my containers.

I do believe it is 1024 _per_ lambda after all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question is old, but a suitable answer may help others in the future. The limit as correctly noted in the question is [1,024](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/gettingstarted-limits.html#function-configuration-deployment-and-execution) outbound connections per Lambda function. However this limit is only for the life cycle of the container. There are currently no public documents stating the length of the life cycle, however through my own testing it resulted in the following:

- A new container is created after 5 minutes of idle time for the Lambda function
- A new container is created after 60 minutes of frequent use of the Lambda function
- A new container is created on any update to the code or configuration of the Lambda

A final note on the new containers, when a new container is created it will run all of your code from the start whereas invoking a warm container will just invoke the handler, skipping the loading of the libraries etc. As this is the case it is a best practice to implement connection pooling and declare the connection outside of the handler so that it can be reused in subsequent invokes, examples of this can be found in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/node-reusing-connections.html)